# Extract rows between sequential pairs of values in list from another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, filtering, matching

I have a df of indices corresponding to special events that occur in each trial in a study. The indices are really pairs (2 per trial) that specify the beginning and end of the special events.

`event_df.head(16)`

```
    subject  trial  indices
0         1      1        7
1         1      1       14
2         1      2       28
3         1      2       33
4         2      1       40
5         2      1       48
6         2      2       62
7         2      2       67
8         3      1       80
9         3      1       86
10        3      2       93
11        3      2       99
12        4      1      113
13        4      1      120
14        4      2      130
15        4      2      139
```

I have another df with spatial coordinates of the participants over the entire experiment, as such -

`player_df.head(72)`

```
       subject  trial  x_coords  y_coords  t_coords
0          1      1         2         1       100
1          1      1         2         2       198
2          1      1         3         1       284
3          1      1         4         2       376
4          1      1         5         3       469
5          1      1         5         3       560
6          1      1         4         2       651
7          1      1         6         1       748
8          1      1         5         2       851
9          1      1         6         2       949
10         1      1         7         3      1056
11         1      1         8         4      1160
12         1      1         2         1       102
13         1      1         2         2       201
14         1      1         3         1       300
15         1      1         4         2       395
16         1      1         5         3       489
17         1      1         5         3       591
18         1      2         4         2       684
19         1      2         6         1       778
20         1      2         5         2       871
21         1      2         6         2       977
22         1      2         7         3      1070
23         1      2         8         4      1168
24         1      2         2         1       101
25         1      2         2         2       203
26         1      2         3         1       305
27         1      2         4         2       404
28         1      2         5         3       499
29         1      2         5         3       596
30         1      2         4         2       692
31         1      2         6         1       798
32         1      2         5         2       893
33         1      2         6         2       995
34         1      2         7         3      1089
35         1      2         8         4      1194
36         2      1         2         1       100
37         2      1         2         2       198
38         2      1         3         1       284
39         2      1         4         2       376
40         2      1         5         3       469
41         2      1         5         3       560
42         2      1         4         2       651
43         2      1         6         1       748
44         2      1         5         2       851
45         2      1         6         2       949
46         2      1         7         3      1056
47         2      1         8         4      1160
48         2      1         2         1       102
49         2      1         2         2       201
50         2      1         3         1       300
51         2      1         4         2       395
52         2      1         5         3       489
53         2      1         5         3       591
54         2      2         4         2       684
55         2      2         6         1       778
56         2      2         5         2       871
57         2      2         6         2       977
58         2      2         7         3      1070
59         2      2         8         4      1168
60         2      2         2         1       101
61         2      2         2         2       203
62         2      2         3         1       305
63         2      2         4         2       404
64         2      2         5         3       499
65         2      2         5         3       596
66         2      2         4         2       692
67         2      2         6         1       798
68         2      2         5         2       893
69         2      2         6         2       995
70         2      2         7         3      1089
71         2      2         8         4      1194
72         3      1         2         1       100
73         3      1         2         2       198
74         3      1         3         1       284
75         3      1         4         2       376
76         3      1         5         3       469
77         3      1         5         3       560
78         3      1         4         2       651
79         3      1         6         1       748
80         3      1         5         2       851
81         3      1         6         2       949
82         3      1         7         3      1056
83         3      1         8         4      1160
84         3      1         2         1       102
85         3      1         2         2       201
86         3      1         3         1       300
87         3      1         4         2       395
88         3      1         5         3       489
89         3      1         5         3       591
90         3      2         4         2       684
91         3      2         6         1       778
92         3      2         5         2       871
93         3      2         6         2       977
94         3      2         7         3      1070
95         3      2         8         4      1168
96         3      2         2         1       101
97         3      2         2         2       203
98         3      2         3         1       305
99         3      2         4         2       404
100        3      2         5         3       499
101        3      2         5         3       596
102        3      2         4         2       692
103        3      2         6         1       798
104        3      2         5         2       893
105        3      2         6         2       995
106        3      2         7         3      1089
107        3      2         8         4      1194
108        4      1         2         1       100
109        4      1         2         2       198
110        4      1         3         1       284
111        4      1         4         2       376
112        4      1         5         3       469
113        4      1         5         3       560
114        4      1         4         2       651
115        4      1         6         1       748
116        4      1         5         2       851
117        4      1         6         2       949
118        4      1         7         3      1056
119        4      1         8         4      1160
120        4      1         2         1       102
121        4      1         2         2       201
122        4      1         3         1       300
123        4      1         4         2       395
124        4      1         5         3       489
125        4      1         5         3       591
126        4      2         4         2       684
127        4      2         6         1       778
128        4      2         5         2       871
129        4      2         6         2       977
130        4      2         7         3      1070
131        4      2         8         4      1168
132        4      2         2         1       101
133        4      2         2         2       203
134        4      2         3         1       305
135        4      2         4         2       404
136        4      2         5         3       499
137        4      2         5         3       596
138        4      2         4         2       692
139        4      2         6         1       798
140        4      2         5         2       893
141        4      2         6         2       995
142        4      2         7         3      1089
143        4      2         8         4      1194
```

I would like to use the indices column in the first df (event_df) and extract all of the rows in between (and including) those indices in another dataframe, player_df on a trial by trial basis.

The expected output would be all of the rows between the sequential pairs (per trial only). Note that I don't want rows between all sequential pairs - only those corresponding to the same trial number.

filtered_df

```
            subject  trial  x_coords  y_coords  t_coords
7          1      1         6         1       748
8          1      1         5         2       851
9          1      1         6         2       949
10         1      1         7         3      1056
11         1      1         8         4      1160
12         1      1         2         1       102
13         1      1         2         2       201
14         1      1         3         1       300
28         1      2         5         3       499
29         1      2         5         3       596
30         1      2         4         2       692
31         1      2         6         1       798
32         1      2         5         2       893
33         1      2         6         2       995
40         2      1         5         3       469
41         2      1         5         3       560
42         2      1         4         2       651
43         2      1         6         1       748
44         2      1         5         2       851
45         2      1         6         2       949
46         2      1         7         3      1056
47         2      1         8         4      1160
48         2      1         2         1       102
62         2      2         3         1       305
63         2      2         4         2       404
64         2      2         5         3       499
65         2      2         5         3       596
66         2      2         4         2       692
67         2      2         6         1       798
80         3      1         5         2       851
81         3      1         6         2       949
82         3      1         7         3      1056
83         3      1         8         4      1160
84         3      1         2         1       102
85         3      1         2         2       201
86         3      1         3         1       300
93         3      2         6         2       977
94         3      2         7         3      1070
95         3      2         8         4      1168
96         3      2         2         1       101
97         3      2         2         2       203
98         3      2         3         1       305
99         3      2         4         2       404
113        4      1         5         3       560
114        4      1         4         2       651
115        4      1         6         1       748
116        4      1         5         2       851
117        4      1         6         2       949
118        4      1         7         3      1056
119        4      1         8         4      1160
120        4      1         2         1       102
130        4      2         7         3      1070
131        4      2         8         4      1168
132        4      2         2         1       101
133        4      2         2         2       203
134        4      2         3         1       305
135        4      2         4         2       404
136        4      2         5         3       499
137        4      2         5         3       596
138        4      2         4         2       692
139        4      2         6         1       798
```

I've tried filtering but am not sure how to do this taking into account the trial by trial component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If, as you say, `event_df` indices are in pairs of start and end values, you can create a list of those pairs and then filter the second dataframe using that list:

(I am only using the first two trials for subject 1)

```
pairs = [tuple(event_df.indices[x:x+2]) for x in range(0, len(event_df.indices), 2)]
print(pairs)
[(7, 14), (28, 33)]

res = pd.concat([player_df.iloc[start:end] for start, end in pairs])
print(res)
#   subject trial   x_coords    y_coords    t_coords
# 7       1     1          6           1         748
# 8       1     1          5           2         851
# 9       1     1          6           2         949
# 10      1     1          7           3        1056
# 11      1     1          8           4        1160
# 12      1     1          2           1         102
# 13      1     1          2           2         201
# 14      1     1          3           1         300
# 28      1     2          5           3         499
# 29      1     2          5           3         596
# 30      1     2          4           2         692
# 31      1     2          6           1         798
# 32      1     2          5           2         893
# 33      1     2          6           2         995
```